# Why one of this tests with done/await works and the other one do not?

Tags: angular, unit-testing, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I have this async method that I want to test:

```
async getGeneralStats(): Promise<GeneralStats> {
    console.log("getGeneralStats()");

    let recoveredGeneralStats = await this.storage.get(StorageKeyItems.GeneralStats);
    console.log("recoveredGeneralStats", recoveredGeneralStats);

    if (!recoveredGeneralStats) {
        console.warn("There were no general stats, creating new one")
        this.generalStats = new GeneralStats();
        await this.storage.set(StorageKeyItems.GeneralStats, this.generalStats);
    } else {
        this.generalStats = recoveredGeneralStats;
        console.log("Recovered GeneralStats : ");
        console.dir(this.generalStats)
    }

    console.log("Returning from getGeneralStats")
    return this.generalStats;
}
```

I want to test to things (to beging with): 1. If `storage.get` is called and if `storage.set` is called when `storage.get` returns null.

The first test works and it is in this way:

```
    it("should GET the GeneralStats from Storage Service ", ((done) => {
        // Arrange
        let spy = spyOn(storage, 'get').and.callFake((storageKey) => {
            done();
            return Promise.resolve(null);
        })

        // Act
        statisticsProvider.getGeneralStats();

        // Assert
        expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalledWith(StorageKeyItems.GeneralStats);
    }));
```

But when I try to run the second test in the same way It fails:

```
    it("should SET GeneralStats in Storage if not General Stats were retrieved ", ((done) => {
        // Arrange
        spyOn(storage, 'get').and.callFake((storageKey) => {
            console.log("spyGet was called");
            return Promise.resolve(null);
        })

        let spySet = spyOn(storage, 'set').and.callFake((storageKey, value) => {
            console.log("spySet was called");
                          done();
            return Promise.resolve(null);
        })

        // Act
        statisticsProvider.getGeneralStats();

        // Assert
            expect(spySet).toHaveBeenCalledWith(StorageKeyItems.GeneralStats,statisticsProvider.generalStats);

    }));
```

The fail error says : `"Expected spy set to have been called with [ 'GeneralStats', undefined ] but it was never called."` but the console log says other thing:

```
getGeneralStats()
spyGet was called
recoveredGeneralStats null
There were no general stats, creating new one
spySet was called
FAILED StatisticsProvider #getGeneralStats should SET GeneralStats in Storage if not General Stats were retrieved 
Returning from getGeneralStats
ERROR Expected spy set to have been called with [ 'GeneralStats', undefined ] but it was never called.
```

I have no idea why it says it was not called when it was. I even tried to "cheat" and make a variable that changes to true when the spySet is called but it stills does not work.

```
    it("should SET GeneralStats in Storage if not General Stats were retrieved ", ((done) => {
        let spyWasCalled = false;
        // Arrange
        spyOn(storage, 'get').and.callFake((storageKey) => {
            console.log("spyGet was called");
            return Promise.resolve(null);
        })


        let spySet = spyOn(storage, 'set').and.callFake((storageKey, value) => {
            console.log("spySet was called");
            spyWasCalled = true;
            return Promise.resolve(null);
        })

        // Act
        statisticsProvider.getGeneralStats().then(() => {
            done();

        });

        // Assert
        expect(spyWasCalled).toBeTruthy();
    }));
```

If I put the `expect()` in a `.then` after I call my method the test past but why I didn't need it before?

```
    it("should SET GeneralStats in Storage if not General Stats were retrieved ", ((done) => {
        // Arrange
        spyOn(storage, 'get').and.callFake((storageKey) => {
            console.log("spyGet was called");
            return Promise.resolve(null);
        })

        let spySet = spyOn(storage, 'set').and.callFake((storageKey, value) => {
            console.log("spySet was called");

            return Promise.resolve(null);
        })

        // Act
        statisticsProvider.getGeneralStats().then(() => {

            // Assert
            expect(spySet).toHaveBeenCalledWith(StorageKeyItems.GeneralStats, statisticsProvider.generalStats);
            done();
        });

    }));
```

Comment: Because the first call you're testing is the first time the function under test yields control, so is effectively happening synchronously.

Comment: Ah!!!! that makes that makes sense. Since I just have to know if this function is called then I could just let it in this way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both test cases give inconsistent test results. Because:

1. `expect()` may be executed before the target function completed its command due to asynchronous works it has. - When the test cases run, `getGeneralStats()` gives a `Promise` and **may or may not** move on to run `expect()` which may result in failure.
2. `done()` in the wrong place. The purpose of `done()` is to be called when the asynchronous test case has been completed. So, you should call it after `expect()` **and** when you're sure that all the asynchronous executions are finished. - in first (and second) test case, it might not run the `expect()` at all! Because `done()` may be called before `expect()` inside those callFakes.

To validate, add more `console.log()` before `expect()` (or after too). So you can see if the callFake closure runs before or after the expect.

**What I suggest**

Since the function under test has asynchronous works, you have to expect the result in async manner too.

Jasmine has documented [here](https://jasmine.github.io/tutorials/async).

You can either use `async/await`, `Promise`, or `done()`. Here is the example using `async/await`:

```
it("should SET GeneralStats in Storage if not General Stats were retrieved ", (async () => {
    // Arrange
    spyOn(storage, 'get').and.callFake((storageKey) => {
        console.log("spyGet was called");
        return Promise.resolve(null);
    })

    let spySet = spyOn(storage, 'set').and.callFake((storageKey, value) => {
        console.log("spySet was called");
        return Promise.resolve(null);
    })

    // Act
    await statisticsProvider.getGeneralStats();

    // Assert
    expect(spySet).toHaveBeenCalledWith(StorageKeyItems.GeneralStats, statisticsProvider.generalStats);

}));
```

Comment: Thanks for the link, I didn't saw that part before, I tried to use before `await` but forgot completely to wrap the test in an `async` function. I suppose I do not have to wrap the jasmines `await` into a `try/catch` block, or?

Comment: No, if you don't expect the function under test to throw anything. But if it happens, the test case will just fail.